# Troubles with specific app in Bluestacks - tried some alternatives - are there more?

Tags: virtualbox, android, vmware-workstation

I am having troubles with Bluestacks Android. One specific app is not working, although it works on my phone.

Could you tell me if there are better alternatives?

I tried:
Bluestacks (doesnt work)

youwave Android (doesnt boot anymore after some time - without doing something, apparently a bug)

Android X86 (I have troubles installing it in Virtualbox or VMWare)

Andy Android (Installs VMware Player, killing my VMware Workstation installation - not possible without vmware Player)

Are there some other alternatives I havent tried?

Answer (score 0):

There are other several android emulators available as freeware
I suggest you to try [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) which I've found very good because it will give you a choice to select device configuration as per the smart phones of well known brands available in market. Another several emulators that I've used are:

[AirDroid](https://www.airdroid.com/)

[MEmu](http://www.memuplay.com/)